# Why is the string length showing up in the URL?

Tags: php, arrays, url

I am trying to pass an array through a url. I have tried encoding the URL, serializing the URL, serializing and encoding the URL, and no matter what I do, the length of the strings is coming up in the url.

For example, if I pass the array through a URL this way:

```
<a href='http://splitsum.com/samples/your_store/checkout_form2.php?arr=<?PHP echo serialize($order); ?>'>Next Page</a>
```

The resulting URL looks like this (with the string count printed out):

> .....s:15:%22shipping_method%22;s:20:%22Flat%20Rate%20(Best%20Way)%22;.....

Does anyone know why this is happening?  I can var_dump the entire array (and see the string counts on the page) but I cant seem to print individual values in the array.  Could it have something to do with a problem in the URL and the printing of the string length?

Thanks!

Comment: That's how [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) works.  That's the format it uses.  I'd suggest using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length is appearing because you're using [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize).  That how it outputs.  It's used to store a PHP variable, so that it can be loaded back into PHP again.  It's output format contains the length of arrays/strings.

This is the wrong tool for this job.  You want to use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) here instead.

```
<a href='http://splitsum.com/samples/your_store/checkout_form2.php?<?PHP echo http_build_query(array('arr' => $order)); ?>'>Next Page</a>
```

Then `$_GET['arr']` in `checkout_form2.php` will be your `$order` array.

Comment: I think i may have spoken too soon....when i tried var_dump I only get the first value in the array.  Any idea why that might be happening?  I do see the entire array in the URL, so the data did make it through.

Comment: Did you change your code to look like mine?  Notice how I removed the `arr=` from the URL.

Comment: That was it!!  Thanks again!  The var_dump NOW does print out the entire array, but I still get a Null value when I try to print an element of the array.

Comment: @JennyMoniz: How are you trying to access it?  It should be like: `$_GET['arr']['shipping_method']`

Comment: Looks like my comment didn't make it though -- it turns out I had an array within an array.  I was abel to access the value once i figured out that.  But, i could not have done it without your help.  Seriously.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using `serialize()`. You should be using `urlencode()` instead.

serialize is intended to take internal arbitrary data structures, and encode them into a portable format for re-use in a PHP system somewhere else. It does *NOT* produce code that is guaranteed valid in a URL context. Basically you're using a hammer to pound in a screw. Use a screwdriver instead.

Note that urlencode will not accept an array. Perhaps `http_build_query()` would be more appropriate

Comment: Just tried http_build_query() and it fixed the issue!  Thanks so much!